# Excel - Place Changing Text of Cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I know there are probably multiple ways of accomplishing what I'm about to inquire, but I don't have full understanding of excel's functional capacity so I'm working with what I know.

Here's how the set up looks in my excel workbook.

```
  |---|---------------------|--------------------|---------------------|
  |   |          A          |         B          |         C           |    
  |---|---------------------|--------------------|---------------------|
  | 1 |image_north.001.jpg  |image_north.002.jpg |         x           |
  |---|---------------------|--------------------|---------------------|
  | 2 |image_south.002.jpg   image_south.002.jpg |         y           | 
  |---|---------------------|--------------------|---------------------|
```

And Cell C1 (x) contains all of this below....

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
  <TABLE>
  <TBODY>
  <TR>
    <TD><IMG style="HEIGHT: 200px; WIDTH: auto" 
    src="https://example.web.link/image/property/" width=486 height=647> 
    </TD>
    <TD><IMG style="HEIGHT: 200px; WIDTH: auto" 
     src="https://example.web.link/image/property/" width=486 height=647> 
    </TD>
    </TR>
</TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

What formula do I have to write to get this output on C1 itself or D1?

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
  <TABLE>
  <TBODY>
  <TR>
    <TD><IMG style="HEIGHT: 200px; WIDTH: auto" 
    src="https://example.web.link/image/property/**image_north.001.jpg**" 
    width=486 height=647> 
    </TD>
    <TD><IMG style="HEIGHT: 200px; WIDTH: auto" 
     src="https://example.web.link/image/property/**image_north.002.jpg**" 
     width=486 height=647> 
    </TD>
    </TR>
</TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

**Y would just be a matter of dragging the formula down.

I guess what I'm not able to figure out is how to INSERT string into string. I tried making the template into a formula by placing "=" before it, but I kept getting an error.

May I get some help with this please?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you able to customize the text (template) in cell C1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the C1 template with this text:

Notice the placeholders after "property/" -> "< image 1>" and "< image 2>"

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
  <TABLE>
  <TBODY>
  <TR>
    <TD><IMG style="HEIGHT: 200px; WIDTH: auto" 
    src="https://example.web.link/image/property/<image 1>" width=486 height=647> 
    </TD>
    <TD><IMG style="HEIGHT: 200px; WIDTH: auto" 
     src="https://example.web.link/image/property/<image 2>" width=486 height=647> 
    </TD>
    </TR>
</TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

In D1 enter this formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(C1;"<image 1>";A1);"<image 2>";B1)
```

This would be the set up

[image]

Comment: Aaaaa! This worked! Thank you! However, I had to use commas instead of semicolons for the formula to work in my excel environment? Why is that? Also, why did you have to use a substitute function inside another substitute function for this work (for learning purposes)? Oh man, you have no idea how much time you saved me. Thank you! Thumbs up!!!!

Comment: Great! The comma or semicolon is because my regional settings are in spanish. The two substitutes functions are necessary because you need one for each text you replace